# Baking normals of overlapping objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, normals

As a learning project, I've been modeling the [Albion Laird](http://www.kultofathena.com/product.asp?item=ANS6&name=Albion%20Laird%20Sword) sword. I've got a rather high polygon mesh. Since I plan using this mesh on a game prototype, I've created a lower resolution mesh, with the same proportions as the original, so I could bake the high normals into a texture for the simpler mesh. Below are both meshes side-by-side:

[image: Top: Low-poly; Bottom: High-poly]

Now, I've placed them both at the same location, unwrapped the low-res, selected the high-poly then the low-poly, baked "Selected to Active" tangent normal maps, just like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7PQGgz1RII), except I'm using Cycles.

[image: Both meshes overlapped]
[image: Selection and Bake Settings]

I then attached the freestanding Image Texture on the shader's Normal input, and this was the result:

[image: The material setup]
[image: Resulting render]

As you can notice, it looks nothing like the high-poly render and contains heavy artifacts. I assume this is due to the overlap in the handle area, but how can I circumvent that without distorting any of the meshes? Here's the high-poly render for reference:

[image: High-poly mesh render]

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on the low poly model?

Comment: Try to increase ray distance in the bake settings

Comment: @Denis No modifiers on the low poly, however the high poly is actually using a mirror. Will try in a second

Comment: I think its the ray distance in the bake settings, your objects are over 20 meters in size so you would need to scale them down or increase ray distance a lot.

Comment: @Denis, that improved the situation a dramatically, see [this render of the map baked with a ray distance of 50](https://gyazo.com/06309b80a130b36e4dc4a6b4eda3d0b2). But there are still some artifacts, mainly on the pommel and crossguard (the round and side-pointing things)

Comment: You might need to adjust the low poly model better to the high poly model,    because whatever is visible perpendicularly to the face will be baked on the texture.

Comment: @Denis Oh, after doing some adjustments (some faces were pointing outside the high poly model), this is looking much finer. [A screenshot of the preview](https://gyazo.com/679909e72739632180d1787a226d6a98). Now the bevels look like bevels! Can you post your instructions as an answer?

Comment: Your normal map setup is missing a node.  Vector->Normal should come after the image texture and before the shader node.